# Why is MySQL consuming so much memory?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql 5.6.36 database where the size is ~35G running on CentOS 7.3 with 48G of RAM.

[**UPDATE** 17-08-06] I will update relevant information [here](https://github.com/julio-garcia-fc/mysql-problems).

I am seeing that my server runs out of memory and crashes even with ~48G of RAM. I could not keep it running on 24G, for example. A DB this size should be able to run on much less. Clearly, I a missing something fundamental.

[**UPDATE**: 17-08-05] By crashes, I mean mysqld stops and restarts with no useful information in the log, other than restarting from a crash. Also, with all this memory, I got this error during recovery:

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in tablespace ./ca_uim/t_qos_snapshot.ibd (table ca_uim/t_qos_snapshot)
```

The relevant portion of my config file looks like this [**EDITED** 17-08-05 to add missing lines]:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
lower_case_table_names = 1
symbolic-links=0
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
max_allowed_packet = 32M
max_connections = 300
table_definition_cache=2000
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 18G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 9
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_file_per_table=1

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

It was an oversight to use file per table, and I need to change that (I have 6000 tables, and most of those are partitioned).

After running for a short while (one hour), mytop shows this:

```
MySQL on 10.238.40.209 (5.6.36)    load 0.95 1.08 1.01 1/1003 8525 up 0+01:31:01 [17:44:39]
 Queries: 1.5M     qps:  283 Slow:    22.0         Se/In/Up/De(%):    50/07/09/01
 Sorts:     27 qps now:  706 Slow qps: 0.0  Threads:  118 (   3/   2) 43/28/01/00 
 Key Efficiency: 100.0%  Bps in/out: 76.7k/176.8k   Now in/out: 144.3k/292.1k
```

And free shows this:

```
# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            47G         40G        1.5G        8.1M        5.1G        6.1G
Swap:          3.9G        508K        3.9G
```

Top shows this:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                             
2010 mysql     20   0 45.624g 0.039t   9008 S  95.0 84.4  62:31.93 mysqld
```

How can this be? Is this related file per table? The entire DB could fit in memory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you use a `join` then the result can be many times the table size. There could be other processes using the memory. What query is being run when the server crashes? When you say 'crashes' does it simply stop responding across any application, or only MySQL? Lastly, to be sure, you have 283 queries per second?

Comment: Verify your memory configuration with http://mysqltuner.pl

Comment: `mysql> show processlist;` will help to discern on SO or [SF].

Comment: *"There is not much else in the file."*  You may be overlooking something that seems insignificant to you... for example, `thread_cache_size`, which I have always believed strands allocated memory under certain workloads.  Changing `table_definition_cache` from the default is usually unnecessary, and, really, you should strive to customize as few parameters as possible.  And whatever you do, don't change anything simply because mysqltuner said to.

Comment: @AuntJamaima, not, according to htop, mysql dwarfs everything else by a whole lot, in terms of memory. I am not able to pin down the offending query. Yes, 283 qps according to mytop. Is that too much? Too little?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I need to research table_definition_cache. That was "recommended". For the innodb parameter changes, I followed this informatio: http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/01/how-to-allocate-innodb-buffer-pool-size-in-mysql.html. The changes did not help.

Comment: I should have mentioned, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is critical and does of course need to be set to an appropriate value.  It's tinkering with other "tunable" parameters that can result in performance degradation.  That value seems fine.  Anything you tweaked without knowing *exactly* why you tweak it, you should undo.  There are vast hordes of well intentioned but ill-informed people giving advice on the Internet about MySQL.

Comment: *"I mean mysqld stops and restarts with no useful information in the log"*  That is not technically a MySQL crash, then.  `sudo egrep 'kernel|oom' /var/log/messages`.

Comment: I am intrigued by the number of sleeps.
Is it a symptom? Depends: 
How many applications are in uimserver1?
How many concurrent users on those applications?
Are using connection pools? 
Are using persistant connections?
If you had long running queries you would see them once in a while in the process list, however, you have a lot of unused connections (and that is why I think increasing thread cache will not help) which is normal when time is close to 0. 
Are those broked/abandonded connections holding on resources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I resolved the issue. I appreciate all the insight from those who responded. The solution is very strange, and I cannot explain why this solves the problem, but it does. What I did was add the following line to my.cnf:

```
log_bin
```

You may, in addition, need to add the following:

```
expire_logs_days = <some number>
```

We have seen at least one instance where the logs accumulated and filled up a disk. The default is 0 (no auto removal). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days

Comment: expire_log_days is deprecated as of MySQL 8: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days

Answer (score 25):

In your **my.cnf (MySQL configuration)** file:

Add a setting in [mysqld] block

```
[mysqld]

performance_schema = 0
```

---

For MySQL 5.7.8 onwards, you will have to add extra settings as below:

```
[mysqld]

performance_schema = 0

show_compatibility_56 = 1
```

**NOTE: This will cut your Memory usage to more than 50%-60%. "show_compatibility_56" is optional, for some cases it works, better to check it once added to the config file.**

Comment: On my DO box With LEMP stack (MySQL 8), mysqld went from around 44% to around 16-17% by adding performance_schema=0 in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. The other option (show_compatibility_56) caused mysqld to not restart properly. Note, I have no need for performance schema to be on - make sure you don't need it too before turning off

Comment: The 'show_compatibility_56' parameter depends on the stack which you are using. I will research about this and will make sure that I add the correct stack for this setting. Thank you for the comment @LukeMadhanga

Comment: @AbhishekMugal What should I do if I use Mysql 8+ where this variable **show_compatibility_56** is removed? If I save this variable in my mysqld.cnf and start mysql - in the log file I get ```unknown variable 'show_compatibility_56=1'```

Comment: Went down from 800MB to 240MB memory usage on macOS Sonoma. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Results are stored and fed from memory and given that you're running 283 per second, there's probably a lot of data at any given moment being dished out.

I would think that you are doing a good job squeezing a lot out of that server. Consider the tables are one thing, then the schema involved for 6000 tables, plus the fact that you're pulling 283 queries per second against a 35 GB database and that those results are held in memory while they are being served. The rest of us might as well learn from you.

Regarding the stopping and restarting of MySQL

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in tablespace ./ca_uim/t_qos_snapshot.ibd (table ca_uim/t_qos_snapshot)
```

Your might consider trying
 `innodb_flush_method=normal` which is recommended [here](http://webdevelopmentscripts.com/23-solved-innodb-error-space-header-page-consists-of-zero-bytes-xampp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576745/innodb-error-space-header-page-consists-of-zero-bytes-in-data-file-ibdata1), but I can't promise it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I would check **table_open_cache**. You have a lot of tables and it is clearly reflected in avg opened files per second:  about 48 when a normal value is between 1 and 5. 
That is confirmed by the values of `Table_open_cache_misses` and `Table_open_cache_overflows`,
ideally those values should be cero. Those means failed attempts to use cache and in consequence wasted memory.
You should try increasing it at least to 3000 and see results.

Since you are on CentOS:

1. I would double check that `ulimit` it is unlimited or about 20000 for your 6000 tables.
2. Consider set `swappiness` to 1. I think it is better to have some swapps (while observing) than crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [www.mysqlcalculator.com](https://www.mysqlcalculator.com) would be a quick way to get a brain check on about a dozen memory consumption factors in less than 2 minutes.

118 active threads may be reasonable but would seem to be causing extreme context switching trying to answer 118 questions simultaneously.

Would love to see your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS  and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES, if you could get them posted.

Comment: I changed the config to the absolute minimal changes that I need to run the app. It runs like a dog and mysql will eventually run out of memory. You can see the information here: https://github.com/julio-garcia-fc/mysql-problems/tree/master/small-config

Answer (score 0):

Please enable the MySQL error log in your usual configuration.
When MySQL crashes, protect the error log before restarting, and add last error-log available to your Question, please.  It should have a clue WHY MySQL is failing.
Running the 'small' configuration will run like a dog, when supporting the volume of activity reported by SHOW GLOBAL STATUS.
Please get back to your usual production configuration.
I am looking at your provided details and will have some tuning suggestions in next 24 hours.  It appears most of the process-list activities are related to replication.  Would that be true?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are a believer in ONLY one change at a time so you can track progress for a configuration reason. 2017-08-07 about 17:00 SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES indicates `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 128M.  Change in `my.cnf` to 24G, shutdown/restart when permitted, please.

**A)** `max_allowed_packet_size` at 1G is likely what you meant in your configuration, considering on 8/7/2017 your remote agents are sending 1G packets for processing on this equipment.  How are remote agents managed in terms of scheduling their sending of data to prevent exhausting all 48G on this host for this single use of memory?  Status indicates `bytes_received` on 8/6/2017 was 885,485,832 from `max_used_connections` of 86 in first 1520 seconds of uptime.

**B)** `innodb_io_capacity` at 200 is likely a significant throttle to your possible IOPS, we run here at 700. sqlio.exe utility was used to guide us in this direction.

**C)** `innodb_io_capacity_max` should be likely be adjusted as well.

**D)** `thread_cache_size` of 11, consider going to 128.

**E)** `thread_concurrency` of 10, consider going to 30.

**F)** I understand the length of `process-list.txt` in the number of Sleep ID's is likely caused by the use of persistent connections.  The connection is just waiting for some additional activity from the client for an extended period of time. 8/8/2017

**G)** STATUS `Com_begin` count is usually very close to `Com_commit` count, not in your case.  8/8/2017 `Com_begin` was 2 and `Com_commit` was 709,910 for 11 hours of uptime.

**H)** It would probably be helpful to see just 3 minutes of a General Log, if possible.

Keep me posted on your progress.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot explain the max_allowed_packet_size. It is explicitly set to 32M in my.cnf. Very strange. I updated the information at https://github.com/julio-garcia-fc/mysql-problems/tree/master/small-config with the latest information, after 11 hours. Added mysqld.log. It is useless because I should have increased the log level. I will fix that and learn about the other settings you mention. I would like to change one thing, but at this point, I am not sure what to change, other that increasing swap space or throwing more memory at that VM.

Comment: yes, I suspended disbelief and added enough memory. Problem solved.