# MySql is giving Error in Xampp. "Error establishing a database connection"?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

Please See Error Logs. Can Anyone Help me?

> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 b7ac InnoDB: Warning: Using 
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED.
>    This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and 
>   with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring page 0 of tablespace 0
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Warning] InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [ERROR] InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1
>   2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 2017-10-13 11:56:46 47020 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: this is simple setup or you have changed setup files

Comment: Visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576745/innodb-error-space-header-page-consists-of-zero-bytes-in-data-file-ibdata1